# How to add user profiles to favorites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application with many users/user profiles. I'd like to allow users to click a 'Add to favorites' button and add the profile they are looking at to their favorites tab. So that when they click the favorites tab they'll be able to see all of the user profiles that they've favorited.

I'm using a HMT association as follows:

**favorite_relationship.rb**

```
class FavoriteRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attributes are ( user_id and favourite_id )
  belongs_to :favorite
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**favorite.rb**

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorite_relationships
  has_many :users, through: :favorite_relationships
end
```

**user.rb** ( appropriate snippit )

```
  has_many :favorite_relationships
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_relationships
  has_many :people_who_favorited_me, through: :favorite_relationships, foreign_key: "favorite_id"
```

**favorites_controller.rb** ( this is a disaster I know )

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :find_user

  def index
    @favorites = @user.favorites
  end

  def create
    @currentuser = current_user
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    @currentuser.favorites << @user
  end

  def destroy
    @favorite = @user.favorites.find_by_user_id params[:id]
    @favorite.destroy unless @favorite.blank?
  end
  end

  private

  def find_user
    @user = current_user
  end

end
```

And I have no idea how to do the view.. any help would be a huge releif.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Thanks for the up vote but any answers? I'm officially stuck :(

Comment: Is there some type of follower relationship?  Why do you have the favoriterelationships model?

Comment: No, no follower relationship.. Just want users to be able to favourite other users, and for other users to be able to favourite that user.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing the following:

```
class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favorite, class_name: 'User'
end
```

You could even use HABTM if you do not plan to use the Favorite other then retrieving Users.

Then:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_users, through: :favorites, source: :favorite
  has_many :users_who_favorited_me, through: favorites, source: :user
end
```

No need for a 3rd entity... At least not in the scenario you described. Then you can do the following:

```
def create
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  current_user.favorites << Favorite.new({favorite: @user}) # Expects the same association type, ie. Favorites wants Favorites
  # OR like this
  # current_user.favorites.create({favorite: @user})
end

def destroy
  @favorite = current_user.favorites.find_by_favorite_id params[:id]
  @favorite.destroy
```

end

### OR

Consider using/understanding a gem if you are having trouble grasping the concept....

https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/